# Consul server unable to join Consul Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, consul

Before I start explaining what my problem is, I would like to point out that I do not have lots of experience with Consul, so please be patient with me :D
I would need your assistance in figuring out what is wrong with the Consul I have deployed in my Azure AKS.
The infrastructure I have looks like this:

- 3 servers running in AKS (Consul version 1.8.4)
- 6 clients running on VMs (Consul version 1.8.0)
- The AKS cluster is Private

Everything was working well, but suddenly, the pods started to die one after the other.
I redeployed Consul running in AKS and now I have the problem that I have only two from three Consul servers running. The third server will be in a Running state for about maybe 30 s and then it will become OOM killed and then enter CrashLoopBackOff status.
When I run the command consul members, I get all the server & clients listed and the problematic pod will be shown as “left”, while the others are being shown as “alive”.
I have also tried to execute the command consul join {ip address} but this gives me the following error message:

/ # consul join 10.0.0.135
Error joining address '10.0.0.135': Unexpected response code: 500 (1 error occurred:
* Failed to join 10.0.0.135: dial tcp 10.0.0.135:8301: connect: connection refused

)
Failed to join any nodes.

I attached the yaml file from my Consul StatefulSet and the error log from the problematic pod.

I must point out that I am having this infrastructure for maybe 2 months and everything was looking fine, and all the pods were healthy and running. In the last 3 days I am dealing with this issue, researching on the internet trying to figure out how can I fix this issue, but with no result.

Could you please help me figure out why suddenly this started happening and eventually help me in solving this issue?

Thanks in advance for your time,

Mike

---

YAMLfile

```
 kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: consul-consul-server
  namespace: consul
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/consul/statefulsets/consul-consul-server
  uid: ddfb4383-8545-457d-8c3a-5dc7ec04f9f2
  resourceVersion: '19294440'
  generation: 11
  creationTimestamp: '2020-10-26T10:19:25Z'
  labels:
    app: consul
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: consul-helm
    component: server
    heritage: Helm
    release: consul
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: consul
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: consul
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consul
      chart: consul-helm
      component: server
      hasDNS: 'true'
      release: consul
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: consul
        chart: consul-helm
        component: server
        hasDNS: 'true'
        release: consul
      annotations:
        consul.hashicorp.com/config-checksum: ca3d163bab055381827226140568f3bef7eaac187cebd76878e0b63e9e442356
        consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject: 'false'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: consul-consul-server-config
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: consul
          image: 'consul:1.8.4'
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - '-ec'
            - |
              CONSUL_FULLNAME="consul-consul"

              exec /bin/consul agent \
                -advertise="${HOST_IP}" \
                -bind=0.0.0.0 \
                -bootstrap-expect=3 \
                -client=0.0.0.0 \
                -config-dir=/consul/config \
                -datacenter=dc1 \
                -data-dir=/consul/data \
                -domain=consul \
                -hcl="connect { enabled = true }" \
                -ui \
                -retry-join=${CONSUL_FULLNAME}-server-0.${CONSUL_FULLNAME}-server.${NAMESPACE}.svc \
                -retry-join=${CONSUL_FULLNAME}-server-1.${CONSUL_FULLNAME}-server.${NAMESPACE}.svc \
                -retry-join=${CONSUL_FULLNAME}-server-2.${CONSUL_FULLNAME}-server.${NAMESPACE}.svc \
                -server
          ports:
            - name: http
              hostPort: 8500
              containerPort: 8500
              protocol: TCP
            - name: serflan
              hostPort: 8301
              containerPort: 8301
              protocol: TCP
            - name: serfwan
              hostPort: 8302
              containerPort: 8302
              protocol: TCP
            - name: server
              hostPort: 8300
              containerPort: 8300
              protocol: TCP
            - name: dns-tcp
              hostPort: 8600
              containerPort: 8600
              protocol: TCP
            - name: dns-udp
              hostPort: 8600
              containerPort: 8600
              protocol: UDP
          env:
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: HOST_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
            - name: NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 800m
              memory: 800Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 800m
              memory: 800Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data-consul
              mountPath: /consul/data
            - name: config
              mountPath: /consul/config
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-ec'
                - |
                  curl http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/status/leader \
                  2>/dev/null | grep -E '".+"'
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 3
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 2
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sh
                  - '-c'
                  - consul leave
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: consul-consul-server
      serviceAccount: consul-consul-server
      hostNetwork: true
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app: consul
                  component: server
                  release: consul
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: data-consul
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
      status:
        phase: Pending
  serviceName: consul-consul-server
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
status:
  observedGeneration: 11
  replicas: 3
  readyReplicas: 2
  currentReplicas: 3
  updatedReplicas: 3
  currentRevision: consul-consul-server-5f84b7b657
  updateRevision: consul-consul-server-5f84b7b657
  collisionCount: 0
```

---

Error Log

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
           Version: '1.8.4'
           Node ID: '017e63cc-bedf-c4c3-2a3c-0dfc0c05594a'
         Node name: 'aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002'
        Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
            Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: [0.0.0.0] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: -1, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 10.0.0.153 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
           Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false, Auto-Encrypt-TLS: false

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2020-12-19T09:27:59.021Z [WARN]  agent: bootstrap_expect > 0: expecting 3 servers
    2020-12-19T09:27:59.044Z [WARN]  agent.auto_config: bootstrap_expect > 0: expecting 3 servers
    2020-12-19T09:27:59.075Z [WARN]  agent.server.snapshot: found temporary snapshot: name=1164-491656-1605996371085.tmp
    2020-12-19T09:27:59.075Z [WARN]  agent.server.snapshot: found temporary snapshot: name=1796-1455900-1608237651961.tmp
    2020-12-19T09:27:59.084Z [WARN]  agent.server.snapshot: found temporary snapshot: name=7621-1555326-1608364051682.tmp
    2020-12-19T09:28:05.099Z [INFO]  agent.server.raft: restored from snapshot: id=7621-1538935-1608350048113
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.735Z [INFO]  agent.server.raft: initial configuration: index=1560707 servers="[{Suffrage:Voter ID:8bdce7bb-464f-19e6-7a36-c165917790a4 Address:10.0.0.173:8300} {Suffrage:Voter ID:804735ae-e812-a843-96a1-7140a17909b6 Address:10.0.0.143:8300}]"
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.735Z [INFO]  agent.server.raft: entering follower state: follower="Node at 10.0.0.153:8300 [Follower]" leader=
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.749Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002.dc1 10.0.0.153
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.749Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: Attempting re-join to previously known node: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1: 10.0.0.173:8302
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.752Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1 10.0.0.173
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.752Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000001.dc1 10.0.0.143
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.752Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: Re-joined to previously known node: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1: 10.0.0.173:8302
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002 10.0.0.153
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.router: Initializing LAN area manager
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: Attempting re-join to previously known node: mapserver-failover: 10.0.0.54:8301
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002.dc1 area=wan
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1 area=wan
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000001.dc1 area=wan
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server: Adding LAN server: server="aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002 (Addr: tcp/10.0.0.153:8300) (DC: dc1)"
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.764Z [INFO]  agent.server: Raft data found, disabling bootstrap mode
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.769Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: image-failover 10.0.0.57
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.769Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000 10.0.0.173
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.769Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: mapserver 10.0.0.53
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.769Z [INFO]  agent.server: Adding LAN server: server="aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000 (Addr: tcp/10.0.0.173:8300) (DC: dc1)"
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.769Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: image 10.0.0.56
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.770Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: mapserver-failover 10.0.0.54
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.770Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000001 10.0.0.143
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.770Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: web-server-01 10.0.0.36
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.770Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: web-server-02 10.0.0.37
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.770Z [INFO]  agent.server: Adding LAN server: server="aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000001 (Addr: tcp/10.0.0.143:8300) (DC: dc1)"
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.770Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: Re-joined to previously known node: mapserver-failover: 10.0.0.54:8301
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.778Z [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=0.0.0.0:8600 network=tcp
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.778Z [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=0.0.0.0:8600 network=udp
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.778Z [INFO]  agent: Started HTTP server: address=[::]:8500 network=tcp
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.778Z [INFO]  agent: started state syncer
==> Consul agent running!
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.779Z [INFO]  agent: Retry join is supported for the following discovery methods: cluster=LAN discovery_methods="aliyun aws azure digitalocean gce k8s linode mdns os packet scaleway softlayer tencentcloud triton vsphere"
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.779Z [INFO]  agent: Joining cluster...: cluster=LAN
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.779Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=[consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc, consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc, consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc]
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.932Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:28:33.972Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: failed to get previous log: previous-index=1561367 last-index=1561020 error="log not found"
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.101Z [INFO]  agent: Synced node info
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.114Z [INFO]  agent: Synced service: service=app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.126Z [INFO]  agent: Synced service: service=administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.184Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.184Z [INFO]  agent: Synced service: service=app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.378Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:28:34.378Z [WARN]  agent: (LAN) couldn't join: number_of_nodes=0 error="3 errors occurred:
    * Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    * Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    * Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

"
     
    2020-12-19T09:30:04.891Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002)
    2020-12-19T09:30:05.287Z [WARN]  agent: Join cluster failed, will retry: cluster=LAN retry_interval=30s error=<nil>
    2020-12-19T09:30:05.927Z [INFO]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Suspect web-server-02 has failed, no acks received
    2020-12-19T09:30:06.786Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: web-server-01 10.0.0.36
    2020-12-19T09:30:07.390Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:08.039Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:08.427Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:14.487Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:15.975Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:15.976Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:16.134Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000 but other probes failed, network may be misconfigured
    2020-12-19T09:30:21.533Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:23.290Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:23.426Z [INFO]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Suspect image-failover has failed, no acks received
    2020-12-19T09:30:23.581Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:27.987Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:29.988Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:30.094Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:32.472Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to image but other probes failed, network may be misconfigured
    2020-12-19T09:30:32.534Z [INFO]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Marking web-server-02 as failed, suspect timeout reached (0 peer confirmations)
    2020-12-19T09:30:32.675Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberFailed: web-server-02 10.0.0.37
    2020-12-19T09:30:34.832Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:35.542Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=[consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc, consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc, consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc]
    2020-12-19T09:30:36.929Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:37.836Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:40.096Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to mapserver-failover but other probes failed, network may be misconfigured
    2020-12-19T09:30:43.635Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:44.534Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: web-server-02 10.0.0.37
    2020-12-19T09:30:45.086Z [INFO]  agent.server.memberlist.wan: memberlist: Suspect aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1 has failed, no acks received
    2020-12-19T09:30:45.836Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:47.386Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000002)
    2020-12-19T09:30:49.724Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:30:50.539Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:51.040Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:30:51.334Z [INFO]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Suspect image-failover has failed, no acks received
    2020-12-19T09:30:53.929Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:54.933Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.wan: memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1)
    2020-12-19T09:30:55.723Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:30:58.039Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:30:58.631Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:01.087Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:02.088Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:31:02.534Z [WARN]  agent: (LAN) couldn't join: number_of_nodes=0 error="3 errors occurred:
    * Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    * Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    * Failed to resolve consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
    2020-12-19T09:31:05.834Z [INFO]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Suspect mapserver-failover has failed, no acks received
    2020-12-19T09:31:05.924Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:07.886Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:11.930Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:12.535Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.wan: memberlist: Was able to connect to aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000.dc1 but other probes failed, network may be misconfigured
    2020-12-19T09:31:12.544Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:14.679Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:15.384Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to web-server-01 but other probes failed, network may be misconfigured
    2020-12-19T09:31:18.586Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:19.085Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:21.229Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:22.583Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to aks-nodepool1-12257257-vmss000000 but other probes failed, network may be misconfigured
    2020-12-19T09:31:22.723Z [INFO]  agent: Synced check: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:23.137Z [INFO]  agent: Synced check: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:23.285Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: mapserver-failover)
    2020-12-19T09:31:23.729Z [INFO]  agent: Synced check: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:25.229Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:25.579Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:27.485Z [WARN]  agent: Check is now critical: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:28.675Z [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: web-server-01)
    2020-12-19T09:31:31.137Z [INFO]  agent: Synced check: check=service:administration_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:31.532Z [INFO]  agent: Synced check: check=service:app_webserver_2
    2020-12-19T09:31:31.698Z [INFO]  agent.server.fsm: snapshot created: duration=5.743467ms
    2020-12-19T09:31:32.922Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:35822: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:32.927Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: skipping application of old log: index=1561084
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.038Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:35824: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.091Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: skipping application of old log: index=1561084
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.171Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:35948: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.232Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to take snapshot: error="cannot take snapshot now, wait until the configuration entry at 1560707 has been applied (have applied 1547895)"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.292Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: skipping application of old log: index=1561084
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.377Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: failed to get previous log: previous-index=1561406 last-index=1561084 error="log not found"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.378Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36164: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.626Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36064: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.627Z [INFO]  agent: Synced check: check=service:app_webserver_1
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.677Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: skipping application of old log: index=156108
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.725Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=[consul-consul-server-0.consul-consul-server.consul.svc, consul-consul-server-1.consul-consul-server.consul.svc, consul-consul-server-2.consul-consul-server.consul.svc]
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.831Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36234: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.833Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36340: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.833Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36444: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.833Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36656: write: broken pipe"
    2020-12-19T09:31:33.833Z [ERROR] agent.server.raft: failed to flush response: error="write tcp 10.0.0.153:8300->10.0.0.143:36440: write: broken pipe"
```

Comment: Did you check the rest pods for logs? Since the pipe is broken, you might see logs on the other end.